# Optimization of pixels rendering

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

I'm currently working on a project with multiple objects (tangible objects).

I have a function called `renderFrame()` executed each frame that :

- takes a pixel array as an argument
- iterates through all objects and ask them if they should change a specific pixel

The problem is that every frame, a new pixel array must be generated an instanciated with these values.
To do this, I simply use a loop :

```java
int[] pixels = new int[4 * WIDTH * HEIGHT];

for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length - 3; i += 4) {
  pixels[i    ] = 0;   // red
  pixels[i + 1] = 0;   // green
  pixels[i + 2] = 0;   // blue
  pixels[i + 3] = 255; // alpha
}
```

Each time I call the function `renderFrame()`, is it best (in terms of calculation speed) creating a new array and fill it thanks to my `for()` loop, or creating a copy of a static pixel "model" array like the following one?

```java
private static int[] pixelsD = new int[4 * WIDTH * HEIGHT];

public void initializeArray() {
  for (int i = 0; i < pixelsD.length - 3; i += 4) {
    pixelsD[i    ] = 0;   // red
    pixelsD[i + 1] = 0;   // green
    pixelsD[i + 2] = 0;   // blue
    pixelsD[i + 3] = 255; // alpha
  }
}

public void renderFrame() {
  int[] pixels = Arrays.copyOf(pixelsD, 4 * WIDTH * HEIGHT);
}
```

Comment: I think the best way to improve this is to make it parallel. You can fire multiple threads and initialize them in parallel to get some speedup

Comment: The way I currently calculate the next frame is based on the last frame, like in a suit. So I can't ^^'.Moreover if an object in the "background" renders after another object in the "foreground", everything is screw up!

Comment: Based on the code you posted you can make it parallel. You can parallelize the for loop and also the copy of the array in the renderFrame() function.

Comment: image processing is always a good target for multithreading and SIMD